# Selenium: how to write comments to "command history frame"?

Tags: selenium

While selenium is running I want to write some text to this window. Is there an unobtrusive way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using [**setContext()**](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#setContext%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

> Writes a message to the status bar and adds a note to the browser-side log.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. I was puzzled because (until now) no one here has ever asked a similar question. And I think the method is misnamed. and the documentation is ambiguous: "status bar" - is this the browser's status bar? - "browser-side log"? What's that again?

Answer (score 1):

I think *the status bar* is on the left of logs window and *the browser-side log* is on the right (Command History). Look at the picture:

[image]

But I'm not sure that it is correct.
Maybe someone else will explain us this issue.

Comment: After a few days working with this, I think this is correct, and I think writing it out on both sides of the window is a useful, practical feature, especially for long-running tests. On the left I can see what my last message was, without much scrolling and filtering other log entries. Maybe it's just me, however, as a part-time tomcat/JEE developer I am confused by this "setContext()" wording/technobabble.